# Best way to represent multilingual database on mongodb

Tags: mongodb

I have a MySQL database to support a multilingual website where the data is represented as the following:

table1

```
id
is_active
created
```

table1_lang

```
table1_id
name
surname
address
```

What's the best way to achieve the same on mongo database?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can either design a schema where you can reference or embed documents. Let's look at the first option of embedded documents. With you above application, you might store the information in a document as follows:

```
// db.table1 schema
{
    "_id": 3, // table1_id
    "is_active": true,
    "created": ISODate("2015-04-07T16:00:30.798Z"),
    "lang": [
        {
            "name": "foo",
            "surname": "bar",
            "address": "xxx"
        },
        {
            "name": "abc",
            "surname": "def",
            "address": "xyz"
        }
    ]
}
```

In the example schema above, you would have essentially embedded the `table1_lang` information within the main `table1`document. This design has its merits, one of them being data locality. Since MongoDB stores data contiguously on disk, putting all the data you need in one document ensures that the spinning disks will take less time to seek to a particular location on the disk. If your application frequently accesses `table1` information along with the `table1_lang` data then you'll almost certainly want to go the embedded route. The other advantage with embedded documents is the atomicity and isolation in writing data. To illustrate this, say you want to remove a document which has a lang key "name" with value "foo", this can be done with one single (atomic) operation:

```
db.table.remove({"lang.name": "foo"});
```

For more details on data modelling in MongoDB, please read the docs **[Data Modeling Introduction](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/core/data-modeling-introduction/)**, specifically **[Model One-to-Many Relationships with Embedded Documents](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/tutorial/model-embedded-one-to-many-relationships-between-documents/)**

The other design option is referencing documents where you follow a normalized schema. For example:

```
// db.table1 schema
{
    "_id": 3
    "is_active": true
    "created": ISODate("2015-04-07T16:00:30.798Z")
}

// db.table1_lang schema
/*
1
*/
{
    "_id": 1,    
    "table1_id": 3,
    "name": "foo",
    "surname": "bar",
    "address": "xxx"
}
/*
2
*/
{
    "_id": 2,    
    "table1_id": 3,
    "name": "abc",
    "surname": "def",
    "address": "xyz"
}
```

The above approach gives increased flexibility in performing queries. For instance, to retrieve all child `table1_lang` documents for the main parent entity `table1` with id 3 will be straightforward, simply create a query against the collection `table1_lang`:

```
db.table1_lang.find({"table1_id": 3});
```

The above normalized schema using document reference approach also has an advantage when you have one-to-many relationships with very unpredictable arity. If you have hundreds or thousands of `table_lang` documents per give `table` entity, embedding has so many setbacks in as far as spacial constraints are concerned because the larger the document, the more RAM it uses and MongoDB documents have a hard size limit of 16MB.

The general rule of thumb is that if your application's query pattern is well-known and data tends to be accessed only in one way, an embedded approach works well. If your application queries data in many ways or you unable to anticipate the data query patterns, a more normalized document referencing model will be appropriate for such case.

Ref:

**[MongoDB Applied Design Patterns: Practical Use Cases with the Leading NoSQL Database By Rick Copeland](http://shop.oreilly.com/product/0636920027041.do)**