# How to transform (or simplify) deep document's object in mongo db aggregate?

Tags: mongodb, aggregation-framework

Iam making aggregate request with mongo db on this exemple collection :

```
{
"_id" : ObjectId("5756e3e0f32d0541149c6d6d"),
"host" : "www.mywebsite.com",
"ip" : "0.0.0.0",
"user_agents" : {
    "dcc0ed6139b2c38f189c9e3c978c675bf4d5ad09" : {    // sha1 of the user agent
        "user_agent" : "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; rv:34.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/34.0",
        "created_at" : ISODate("2016-06-07T15:10:26.000Z"),
        "updated_at" : ISODate("2016-06-20T12:38:53.000Z")
    }
},
"created_at" : ISODate("2016-06-07T15:10:26.000Z"),
"number_visits" : 162,
"updated_at" : ISODate("2016-06-20T12:38:53.000Z"),
"referer" : {
    "84063d912731824c07241f459d95b77cf6be85de" : {   // sha1 of the referer
        "updated_at" : ISODate("2016-06-20T12:38:53.000Z"),
        "referer" : "http://subdomain.website.net/",
        "created_at" : ISODate("2016-06-20T12:38:53.000Z")
    },
     "8a85c599e53662be5b4888b1879168b042e52adc" : {   // sha1 of the referer
       "updated_at" : ISODate("2016-06-20T12:29:32.000Z"),
        "created_at" : ISODate("2016-06-20T12:29:32.000Z"),
        "referer" : "https://www.google.com"
    }
}
}
```

This is a exemple document from my collection, which save every request's ip address with somes informations (`user_agent, referer if exists, host...`).

I would like to perform an `aggregate` to get the `latest user agent` and the `latest referer` saved in the collection (based on `updated_at` field in user agent and refeer abject) and get this result :

```
{
    "_id" : "81.56.17.47",
    "latest_referer" : 'mylast/referer/url',
    "latest_user_agent" : "the_latest_user_agent",
}
```

How can i achieve this ?

Comment: As is currently structured, it would be pretty difficult to use the aggregation framework to achieve the desired result, I can only see MapReduce as the only capable solution unless if you change the schema. Would you consider converting the `"referer"` field to an embedded array field with `key/value` fields rather than hashed keys as this would considerably reduce the complexity of the solution?

Comment: @chridam, in terme of performence, is it the same (embedded array VS objects ) ?

Comment: Wrote a detailed answer [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/29717480/122005)

Comment: do im going to change my schema, thx a lot :)

Comment: @chridam are you talking about a sctructure like this : ['referer' : url/referer, created_at : ********, updated_at : ****** ] ?

Comment: No, like [**this**](https://gist.github.com/chrisdamba/0f63e8d182faeaa7dfe996652d135c89#file-stats-js)

Comment: @chridam i have some problems with the schema you talk about, how to cible a array field fom an upsert ?? and how to update the up^dated_at field of the referer and the user agent ? thx a lot men

Comment: Now, that's a broad subject which warrants creating another question but for the purposes of aggregation, the suggested schema will be easy to query.